I cannot see the Model Propierties in my app Autodesk Forge
I'm working on my Autodesk Forge app. In NodeJs.
I have created DataGrid. In the Model Propierties I can't see the content.
In BIM360 the content of these properties is not visible either.
It does exist in the Revit model of the building.
The Model Propierties are like this: 00-Make, 01-Manufacturer.
Could it be because of the name they have used?
I can see the rest of the properties.
const DATAGRID_CONFIG = {
    requiredProps: ['Fabricante', '00-Marca'],
    columns: [
        { title: 'ID', field: 'dbid' },
        { title: 'Fabricante', field: 'Fabricante' },
        { title: '00-Sistema', field: '00-Marca', width: 150 },
    ],
    groupBy: 'level',
    createRow: (dbid, name, props) => {
        const Fabricante = props.find(p => p.displayName === 'Fabricante')?.displayValue || 'N/A';
       
        const Sistema = props.find(p => p.displayName === '00-Sistema')?.displayValue || 'N/A';
       
        return { dbid, Fabricante,'00-Sistema': Sistema };
    },


By Model Properties, are you using Model Properties API in ACC/BIM 360?
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/overview/field-guide/model-properties/
Or platform Model Derivative API?   Maybe you can point to which endpoint you are calling.
